# Permission error with pandas when I run the executable. PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel

My script recives several inputs and then builds an excel archive. When I run it on IDLE it works perfectly, but when I run the executable it shows me this error:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/directory.../[archivename].xlsx'
[8248] Failed to execute script [archivename]

So, my executable does not build my excel archive. I'm using pandas functions, like DataFrame and .to_excel.

Comment: Permission denied usually means the excel is in use, do you have it opened ?

Comment: No, there's  no file opened.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Works perfect on IDLE but I get the same error.